# c# concurrent IO requests basics

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency

I am struggeling with concurrency in c# and the related async-await pattern.

I am facing a performance problem because I need to use several db providers.
`_schedulesProvider` holds the various providers.
I don't really want to change anything there but my idea was to perform those expensive I/O operation simultaneously.
I know that it would be ideal to use await async here in order not to block the calling thread while waiting for the I/O operations to complete but at the moment I don't really bother about that.

consider following code:

```
//queuing all the expensive code in tasks
    List<Task> scheduleProviderTasks = _schedulesProvider.Select(scheduleProvider =>
                {
                    return
                            Task.Run(() =>
                            {
//expensive I/O operation
                                var schedules = scheduleProvider.Get();

                                if (!schedules.Schedules.Any())
                                {
                                    return;
                                }

//do some stuff with the result
                                schedules.Schedules.ForEach(x =>
                                {
                                   DoSomething(x);

                                });
                            });


                }).ToList();

//run all tasks
scheduleProviderTasks.ForEach(x=>x.RunSynchronously());
```

what I am expecting:

the costs of this operation should now be much lower as the expensive operations are run in parallel.

the current thread is beeing blocked until     `scheduleProviderTasks.ForEach(x=>x.RunSynchronously());`

and therefore all operations has completed.

Is this true?
Should I refactor this code?

Comment: Simply wrapping synchronous code in a `Task.Run` might give you some benefit, but if you abuse this in favour of adopting proper (yielding) async code, you'll bog down your threadpool and run into trouble. If you're going for a refactor, start with your "expensive IO operations" so that they use proper async IO in favour of the sync IO that currently cause these long delays.

Comment: You have already started the `Task`. Whats does `//run all tasks
scheduleProviderTasks.ForEach(x=>x.RunSynchronously());` do?

Comment: Hm in VS the hint for Task.Run states, the a Task will be created that queues the work so I assume the task itself has to be started explicitly. Otherwise I dont see the point in creating tasks. At the moment I wish for beeing able to create threads and join them .

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if Task.WaitAll might be helpful in your situation.

Here is an example of doing 4 x 1-second Tasks in parallel where the total time is 2.6706808 seconds.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {           
        mStopWatch.Start();
        Task[] awaitTasks = mTasks.Select(aTask => Task.Run(() => aTask.TimeConsumingTask())).ToArray();
        Task.WaitAll(awaitTasks);
        Debug.WriteLine("Done @ " + mStopWatch.Elapsed.ToString());
    }
    static Stopwatch mStopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    static ProviderOfLengthyTask[] mTasks = new ProviderOfLengthyTask[]
    {
        new ProviderOfLengthyTask("A"),
        new ProviderOfLengthyTask("B"),
        new ProviderOfLengthyTask("C"),
        new ProviderOfLengthyTask("D")
    };
    class ProviderOfLengthyTask
    {
        public ProviderOfLengthyTask(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }
        public readonly string Name;
        public void TimeConsumingTask()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Debug.WriteLine("Done with " + Name + " @ " + mStopWatch.Elapsed.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Where the output is:

Done with B @ 00:00:01.0638455

Done with A @ 00:00:01.0673050

Done with D @ 00:00:02.5961501

Done with C @ 00:00:02.5962068

Done @ 00:00:02.6706808

Comment: thx for this example but shouldn't this be basically be the same? I'd expect the Task.WaitAll() method simply runs the tasks. I for my part would prefer a better description or a better name for this method like Task.RunAndWait() or something

Comment: For sure I agree that it's basically the same. Not a slam-dunk at all,  but I thought maybe we could eek out a little performance this way, or at least observe it and better understand how the scheduling is going in the OS. In my *real* app that I took this from, it's a matter of updating of about a dozen SQLite databases, keeping the UI responsive in the meantime and awaiting the array with all 12 DB syncs-to-cloud. You can, of course await a WaitAll and this is where the value is for me in my app. A also agree with @Sham that Task.Run(()=>) starts the thread implicitly.